# How can 'behave' be used to test time constraints?

Tags: time, python-behave

I couldn't work out if Stack Overflow is an appropriate site to ask this and if not then what the appropriate site would be! There are so many stack exchange sites now and I didn't want to go through 200 sites :S

When I try and test whether my functions run within X seconds using behave (ie gherkin feature files and behave test steps), the code takes longer to run with behave testing than it would on its own. Especially at the beginning of the test but also in other parts.

Has anybody tested time constraints with behave before and know a workaround to adjust for the extra time that behave adds?
Is this even possible?

EDIT: To show how I'm timing the tests:

```
@when("the Python script provides images to the model")
def step_impl(context):
    context.x_second_requirement = 5
    # TODO: Investigate why this takes so long, when I'm not using behave I can use a 0.8 second timing constraint
    context.start_time = time.time()
    context.car_brain.tick()
    context.end_time = time.time()

@then("the model must not take more than X seconds to produce output")
def step_impl(context):
    assert context.end_time - context.start_time < context.x_second_requirement
```

Cheers,
Milan

Comment: I wouldn't expect behave to add substantial time within the execution of the steps.  Are you timing within the step implementations, or timing the invocation of behave externally?  If you use a step like

```When I perform A
Then B occurs within 500ms
```

And mark the time in the when/then step implementations I would be surprised if the execution adds significant time.  But if you're using an external utility like "time" to measure the time to invoke behave from the command line and exit there may be a significant startup cost to find a parse feature files and such.

Comment: Hi dmattp, thanks for your comment. I'm using time.time within the step implementations.

Comment: I've added an example above @dmattp , I'm wondering even if I use a step like ```When I perform A Then B occurs within 500ms```, how I can implement this timing step without using the external "time" module.